# Change gremlin scala return type List[Nothing] to List[String]

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am having vertices created with some property as "ID" and value to that.
I need to fetch the values of property "ID" as List for all the vertices

My query looks like below

> graph.traversal().V().properties("ID").value().toList

It returns me List[Nothing]

How can i modify the query to get the List[String]

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has no way of telling what type your property has, so you have to tell it. 
Here is a complete example using [gremlin-scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/):

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory
val g = TinkerFactory.createModern.asScala
g.V.value[String]("name").toList //returns List[String]
```

Typically you want to define your schema up front with keys, so that you only have to map those types once and for all:

```
val Name = Key[String]("name")
g.V.value(Name).toList //returns List[String]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
valueMap().getOrElse("ID",0).asInstanceOf[Int]
```